# Installing specific version of node.js and npm in ubuntu image with Dockerfile

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

I would like to know how can update my custom Dockerfile to install Node v6.3.1 and NPM v3.10.6 without breaking what is already in there.

Currently this is my custom file:

```
FROM         ubuntu:16.10

MAINTAINER   Fátima Alves

COPY         . /my-software
WORKDIR        /my-software

RUN          apt-get update          \
                                  && \
             apt-get install -y      \
               python-dev            \
             tesseract-ocr
```

Thanks!

---

Update

Currently my dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM         ubuntu:16.10

MAINTAINER   Fátima Alves

COPY         ./dist            /my-software
COPY         ./s3-config.json  /my-software
COPY         ./_*              /my-software
COPY         ./node_modules    /my-software
WORKDIR                        /dataextractor

RUN          apt-get update          \
                                  && \
             apt-get install -y      \
             curl

RUN         curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - \
            && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And is returning:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -             && apt-get install -y nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Perhaps i'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just follow the usual Ubuntu install instructions, just within the `RUN` statement in your `Dockerfile`

```
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)

Comment: Should i put this after the first RUN?

Comment: Yes. You could use `&&` to have them in the same statement if you wanted, but I would keep them separate for now.

Comment: Ah sorry, you don't need to pipe to sudo after the `curl` command. You are set as root within docker. Have updated the command above.

Comment: one second, let my try this

Comment: Can't test it now as am at work. Maybe try just the first part before the `&&`, see if it works, if so you know its an issue with the second part etc. Another thing to try would be to have them as separate commands: 
`RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - `
`RUN apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: Is there a way to install the exact version as in 8.9.4? In the above case, we are asking for a major version only. I want a specific node version in my container.

Answer (score 1):

## WHY

Because https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions suggests doing the "curl pipe bash" anti-pattern, let's try to make that cleaner.

## WHAT

Since containers are built from a definitive OS and Version we don't need the universality of that bash script.

## HOW

If we examine closely, the https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x we see that it really only does ***2 things*** for Debian:

1. Add [their public key](https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key) to apt's keychain via `apt-key add`
2. Add their [deb repo](https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x) to a newly created file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list`

#### Adding sources

The *2nd thing* we can do really easily. That is simply putting this in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY nodesource.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list
```

Of course you'll need to create `nodesource.list` with content like:

```
deb     https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x trusty main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x trusty main
```

#### Adding a trusted key

The *1st thing* is a bit trickier to new "cleanly". I would rather to add a keychain file to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` than modify the existing `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg` file (which is what `apt-key add` would do).

What they have at the URL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key is a public key, not a keychain. To get a keychain file, we can pipe it [not to `apt-key`, rather] like so:

```bash
curl -s https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | \
gpg --import --no-default-keyring --keyring ./nodesource.gpg
```

That creates `nodesource.gpg` which we can utilize by putting this in your Dockerfile:

```
COPY nodesource.gpg   /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nodesource.gpg
```

#### Install as usual

The crazy spacing and `\` terminated lines is what I use because I tend to have a lot of additional packages to install.

```
# Install software packages
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -qqy \
                         nodejs \
    && \
    apt-get clean
```

You can see the complete Dockerfile at https://gist.github.com/RichardBronosky/f748563dc328b12b39cd864973fcb138#file-dockerfile